# How can I allow users to register with an email using django-rest-framework-social-oauth2?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, registration, python-social-auth

I'd like users to be able to register without using a 3rd party if they so choose. Few sites require a username to login anymore, so I'd like to use emails instead of usernames.

[django-rest-framework-social-oauth2](https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2) combines [python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth) and [django-oauth-toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

python-social-auth includes an [EmailAuth](http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/backends/email.html) backend that should let users register with an email and password. However, I don't understand the implications around using this instead of a Django-specific auth backend, and the docs label it as 'legacy', which sounds a little scary.

In fact, I have no idea how creating accounts, including from 3rd parties, works regarding the Django User Model as it requires a username.

What will I lose using EmailAuth? Is that the ideal way to go here, or is there an alternative?

For reasons I don't understand, Django still doesn't support emails instead of usernames without a custom user model, so regardless I need to use something bespoke or open-source for email-based accounts.

EDIT: python-social-auth just fills the username field with `username = email.split('@', 1)[0]` as shown [here](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/social/backends/legacy.py). I think I may need to make a custom Django User model and point python-social-auth to it, but I'm not sure how, and I'm not sure if this should still be used via EmailAuth or independantly of python-social-auth.

Comment: When creating a new user I simply copy the email-address into the username field. Only staff users have usernames that are different from their e-mail address. I think this can be done by simply using a custom form. However, I do not know if and how that interferes with python-social-auth.